# Trying to solve $(p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow r))\wedge\neg r\vdash p\rightarrow\neg q$ with natural deduction (fitch style)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm trying to solve the logical problem above, but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No attempt ? No idea ?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

Assume $p→(q→r) ∧ ¬r$, assume $p$, assume $q$.